# Como hallar el numero mayor y menor en Array Bidimensional de 6x7?

Tags: php, array, arraylist, php5

> por cada fila del array bidimensional que imprima el numero mayor y por cada columna el numero menor

```
<?php

$array=array("uno"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)),


                "dos"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)),

               "tres"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)),

               "cuatro"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)),
              "cinco"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)),

               "seis"=>array("1"=>rand(1,300),
                             "2"=>rand(1,300),
                             "3"=>rand(1,300),
                             "4"=>rand(1,300),
                             "5"=>rand(1,300),
                             "6"=>rand(1,300),
                             "7"=>rand(1,300)));

<?
```

Comment: Creo es importante trates primero de resolver el tema en un papel, si no tienes claro como hacerlo en papel nunca vas a poder hacerlo en un programa, busca como recorrer arreglos y como comparar valores, entender eso te ayudará. Te recuerdo que el objetivo principal de esta comunidad no es hacer tareas de programación. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Cómo te dijo Jonathan, es bueno escribir el problema en papel y tratar de hacer un pseudo-codigo para tener mas clara la solución.
De todas formas, yo en tu lugar probablemente usaría [array_column](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php)

```
foreach($array as $key => $subarray){
    $vals = array_column($subarray, $key)
    $min = min($vals);
    $max = max($vals);
}
```

y así podrías ir obteniendo el menor y el mayor de cada uno.
No he probado el codigo con tu array, pero presiento que el indice al ser un String  ("1","2"...) quizás te de problemas.
En el caso de algún problema con ese indice en String, tendrías que recorrer cada lista y comparar cada valor con el otro.
Espero que lo que ya te mostré te ayude a resolver el problema de tu tarea.